# Check to see if integer is one in which each digit is either a zero or a one

Tags: c

What is the efficient way in C program to check if integer is one in which each digit is either a zero or a one ?

example 100 // is correct as it contains only 0 or 1

701 // is wrong

I tried for

```
    int containsZero(int num) {
        if(num == 0)
            return 0;

        if(num < 0)
            num = -num;

        while(num > 0) {
            if(num % 10 == 0)
                return 0;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return -1;
    }

int containsOne(int num) {
    if(num == 0)
        return 0;

    if(num < 0)
        num = -num;

    while(num > 0) {
        if(num % 10 == 1)
            return 0;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ if it is a C question

Comment: Lazy approach: Convert to string, check if each char is '0' or '1'

Comment: i donot want to use string

Comment: Why are you returning 0 or -1? Use standard booleans for boolean functions.

Comment: @Evert why? num can be altered without any problem.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Even lazier approach, use binary where all digits are always 0 or 1.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the worst case you have to check every digit, so you cannot have an algorithm better than `O(d)`, where `d` is the number of digits.

The straight-forward approach satisfies this:

```
int n = 701;
while ( n != 0 && (n % 10) <= 1 )
{
   n /= 10;
}
if ( (n % 10) > 1 )
{
    printf("Bad number\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Good number\n");
}
```

This assumes positive numbers though. To put it into a general function:

```
int tester(int n)
{
   if ( n < 0 )
   {
       n = -n;
   }
   while ( n != 0 && (n % 10) <= 1 )
   {
      n /= 10;
   }
   return ( (n % 10) <= 1 );
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jWyLdl

What are we doing here? We check if the last decimal digit (n % 10) is either 0 or 1, then cut of the last digit by dividing by ten until the number is 0.

---

Now of course there is also another approach.
If you are guaranteed to have e.g. always 32bit integers, a look-up table isn't that large. I think it may be around 2048 entries, so really not that big.

You basically list all valid numbers:
0
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
...

Now you simply search through the list (a binary search is possible, if the list is sorted!). The complexity with linear search would be, of course, worse than the approach above. I suspect binary search beeing still worse in actual performance, as you need to jump  a lot in memory rather than just operating on one number.

Anything fancy for such a small problem is most probably overkill.

Comment: +1 - I like how you got that if-clause off the loop. .. well, kind of ;)

Comment: @Till well we cannot completely eliminate that check. After all, that's what we're supposed to check :D

Comment: effient meaning that...? there must be some bit trick + maybe extra data (not pretending to have a 2^32 elements array...) which can make it O(1)... no time to think about it now, but I will do and come back with an ans, if any ;)

Comment: @ShinTakezou Yeah, look-up table is easy, see my update. However it's O(1) w.r.t. digits of your number, but it's O(L) or O(log L) where L is the length of the table. Which is worse than O(d).

Comment: @stefan at most for 32bit integer you need 2^9 values; this means you can find a way to arrange it so that you have nothing but an array with access O(1), I think it can be done with two comparisons and an array of 256 integers - but I am not sure. It'd be somewaht different for 64bit int (20 decimal digits?)... Anyway, even with O(n), n (num of dec digits) is small enough to make it not worth... but just for the fun of it...

Answer (score 2):

You can peel of every digit and check it. This takes `O(n)` operations.

```
int input;
while (input != 0)
{
  int digit = input %10; //get last digit using modulo
  input = input / 10; //removes last digit using div
  if (digit != 0 && digit != 1)
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
}
return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of, without using strings:

```
while(n)
{
    x = n%10;
    if(x>1)
        return -1;
    n /= 10;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Preamble

Good straightforward algorithms shown in other answer are O(n), being `n` the number for the digits. Since n is small (even using 64bit integer we won't have more than 20 digits), implementing a "better" algorithm should be pondered, and meaning of "efficient" argued; given O(n) algorithms can be considered *efficient*.

### "Solution"

We can think about sparse array since among 4 billions of numbers, only 2^9 (two symbols, 9 "positions") have the wanted property. I felt that some kind of pattern should emerge from bits, and so there could be a solution exploiting this. So, I've dumped all decimal numbers containing only 0 and 1 in hex, noticed a *pattern* and implemented the simplest code exploiting it — further improvements are surely possible, e.g. the "table" can be halved considering that if x is even and has the property, then x+1 has the property too.

The check is only

```
bool only01(uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t i = n & 0xff;
    uint32_t r = n >> 8;
    return map01[i][0] == r || map01[i][1] == r;
}
```

The full table (map01) and the test code are available [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/shintakezou/8441487).

### Timing

A run of the test ("search" for numbers having the property between 0 and 2 billions — no reason to go beyond) with my solution, using `time` and redirecting output to `/dev/null`:

```
real    0m4.031s
user    0m3.948s
```

A run of the same test with another solution, picked from another answer:

```
real    0m15.530s
user    0m15.221s
```

Answer (score 0):

You work with base 10, so, each time check the `% 10`:

```
int justOnesAndZeros(int num) {
    while ( num )
    {
        if ( ( num % 10 != 1 ) && ( num % 10 != 0 ) )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```